Python Regex to only include/extract numbers, decimals and Hyphen (-)
I am not good at regex and have been trying & failing to extract only numbers, decimals and - from a column in python.
Even better if spaces can also be removed but if not even then it is still manageable.
I have tested ^(\d.+)|[-] and ^(\d.+)|[-]?[^a-z]+$/i and ^(\d.+)|[-]?(\d+)? but none of them worked correctly.
Test Cases (Basically these are Ranges from inconsistent format)
28193.13
28913
28913-13
28193.13-28193.13
28193.13 - 28193.13
28193.13 - 28193.13 / cm
 - 28193.13
 -28193.13
 28913-
 28913 -

Dataframe
test_df = pd.DataFrame({"Range": [28193.13,28913,'28913-13','28193.13-28193.13',
'28193.13 - 28193.13','28193.13 - 28193.13 / cm', '- 28193.13','28913-','28913 -']})

test_df

Code tried: test_df['Range'].str.extract(r"^(\d.+)|[-]?[^a-z]+$/i")
Desired Results on above cases:
28193.13
28913
28913-13
28193.13-28193.13
28193.13-28193.13
28193.13-28193.13
-28193.13
-28193.13
28913-
28913-

Issue: I am unable to remove characters from this 28193.13 - 28193.13 / cm with my regex code as the desired result from this would be 28193.13-28193.13.
Tool: I have used this regex test website to test regex code
Appreciate any help.

Can you edit your question and show expected output for each line?

try this
import re
text = "28193.13 - 28193.13 / cm"
new_text = re.sub(r"[^0-9.-]", "", text)
i think this should work
@ViSa

@anubhava I have added desired results of the cases

Try this Python solution. ''.join([''.join(x.split()) for x in re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?: *- *\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*|-', line)])

@WiktorStribiżew this is almost good .. only issue is it is leaving - in last 4 cases

Try re.sub(r'[^0-9.\-]+', '', text_sample).strip(). It passed all of the cases. See here

Please check your question: the last 4 lines contain hyphens, and you say it is expected output. Else, it is just a matter of changing the regex to re.compile(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?: *- *\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*')

@WiktorStribiżew you were right the very first time. I wanted to include hypen in the result and I did a mistake in copying pasting your answer. Please mention your solution in the answer so that I can accept the answer and close the post and Appreciate your help. Thanks alot for decoding this.

Just curious: does re.sub(r'[^0-9.-]+', '', text_sample).strip() work for you, too?

@WiktorStribiżew yes even this does work in my cases

@WiktorStribiżew is there a difference in using re.compile(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?: *- *\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*') or even re.sub() and test_df['Range'].str.extract(r"(\d+)(?:\.\d+)?(?: *- *\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*|-") . Because these regex patterns were working on text but when I am applying this to dataframe/ Series then it is not working

@ViSa You are using Pandas, so just use test_df['Range'].str.replace(r'[^0-9.-]+', '', regex=True)

@WiktorStribiżew thanks. Its working almost correct except in first 2 where I am getting NAN probably because in 1st 2 cases there are no -

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I think this is a good fix with regex.

    # Define the regex pattern to match numbers, decimals, and hyphens
    pattern = r"[\d\.]+(?:-\d+)?"
    # Find all matches
    matches = re.findall(pattern, value)
    # Join matches to form the cleaned value
    cleaned_value = ''.join(matches)
    return cleaned_value

You can also sovle this a bit more robustly:
def clean_value(value):
    # Filter out characters that are not digits, period, or hyphen
    cleaned_value = ''.join([char for char in value if char.isdigit() or char in ['.', '-']])
    return cleaned_value

# Apply the cleaning function to the data
cleaned_data = [clean_value(val) for val in data]```


Use re.sub from built-in regex documentation (re)
Technically, re is not Regex, but for most use-cases re is better due to being built-in with "import re" and not requiring a pip install.
Documentation from link above:
Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl. If the pattern isn’t found, string is returned unchanged. repl can be a string or a function; if it is a string, any backslash escapes in it are processed. That is, \n is converted to a single newline character, \r is converted to a carriage return, and so forth. Unknown escapes of ASCII letters are reserved for future use and treated as errors. Other unknown escapes such as & are left alone. Backreferences, such as \6, are replaced with the substring matched by group 6 in the pattern.
